# optional argument matching in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, gherkin

How do I implement optional argument in cucumber.

I've step definition

```
     When /^I set parameter1 to (.+) and parameter2 to (.+) and parameter3 to (.+)$/ do    |arg1,arg2,arg3|
```

which is triggered by

```
     I set parameter1 to a,b and parameter2 to c,d and parameter3 to e,f
```

How can I make my step definition so it can be triggered by any one of these

```
     I set parameter1 to a,b and parameter2 to c,d and parameter3 to e,f

     I set parameter1 to a,b and parameter2 to c,d

     I set parameter1 to a,b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use tables then

```
When I set parameters
  | parameter_id | value |
  | parameter1   | a,b   |
  | parameter2   | a,b,c |
```

Then in step definition you can iterate over table elements.

```rb
When /^I set parameters$/ do |table|
  puts table.hashes
  #=> { 'parameter1' => 'a,b', 'parameter2' => 'a,b,c' }
end
```

Comment: I want to call this method `def method (a=[],b[]) .... end` with values in each of the value column. That means, for above example the values a,b corresponds to array a=[] and values a,b,c corresponds to array b=[] . I am trying like this `h = table.hashes method(h["parameter1"],h[parameter2])` but its not working.  Can someone please help.